# Adobe Bridge Opening on Login

Tags: macos, system-settings, adobe-bridge

For some reason Adobe Bridge is opening on login, even though my Login Items shows that it is unchecked.

Without uninstalling Adobe Bridge, how can I stop it opening on login?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The checkbox is to hide the application:
[image: Hide Application on login]
Remove it from the list by clicking the "-" button while it is selected.

Comment: erm durgh!!!!!!

Comment: will accept but cant for 12 minutes